# Spring Boot not able to create datasource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to integrate Spring Boot in one of the existing application. So I decided to start with a POC first.
 I downloaded a sample working code from http://www.journaldev.com/3531/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-integration-crud-example-tutorial and tried to integrate Spring Boot. I changed pom.xml and added a new Java class Application. Below are both of them.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.journaldev.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringMVCHibernate</artifactId>
<name>SpringMVCHibernate</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.34</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Application.java

```
package com.journaldev.spring;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource({"classpath*:spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Application {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }
}
```

When I am starting the application I am getting below error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name      'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
at com.journaldev.spring.Application.main(Application.java:17)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
... 27 common frames omitted
```

Below is the servlet-context.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Person</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="personDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.PersonDAOImpl">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="personService" class="com.journaldev.spring.service.PersonServiceImpl">
    <beans:property name="personDAO" ref="personDAO"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Can you post the file where your configure the datasource? What your using a bean or property file

Comment: I have already posted servlet-context.xml file. Please check above.

Comment: Maybe stupid question: any special reason for not directly going the Spring-Boot way? Cause you could leave out all your xml-situps and just state the driver, user and pass and connection will work. And to configure the commons dbcp you don't have to do anything if it is available on classpath.

Comment: First thing, No question is stupid till the time it is extracting some information. 
Answer is:-  We are in process of evaluating Spring Boot for our existing application which are developed earlier. Most of the configurations are done through xmls. We want to take advantage of Spring Boot with minimum code changes and that is why we want to go ahead with xmls. 
On a second thought Spring Boot supports xml configs then why it is not working in this case.

Comment: Where is your `servlet-context.xml` located? Is it in the classpath or in the `WEB-INF` directory. Also you use spring boot and try very hard not to use it then what is the added benefit of using it.

Comment: It is in WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/. Yes I know I am not using feature of Spring Boot. We are in process of evaluating Spring Boot for our existing application which are developed earlier. Most of the configurations are done through xmls. We want to take advantage of Spring Boot with minimum code changes and that is why we want to go ahead with xmls. On a second thought Spring Boot supports xml configs then why it is not working in this case.

Comment: Which benefits do you have when you dont use the benefits of Spring-boot? If you dont want to configure much leave your application as it is. There is no need to go with Spring-boot if you dont want to use the simplicity of it. I think you will run into more issue time to time. I suggest to start a new Spring-boot project and see how easy and fast the configuration and developing is with the features of boot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After lot of hiccups I resolved all the problem and got it working. I have crated a project and uploaded it on github below is the URL of the project.

https://github.com/gauravdubey58/SpringBootLegacy.git

Answer (score 3):

In your `Application.java` file, try to exclude `DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration` too. For example:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={
    DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class
})
```

You could try runnable example [here](https://github.com/xsalefter/stackoverflowmvn/tree/so-36684444). Make sure that branch for this issue is "so-36684444", and align the JDBC connection as well.

In your `Application.java` file, I added this line:

```
System.out.println(">>> Datasource instance: " + ctx.getBean("dataSource"));
System.out.println(">>> TransactionManager instance: " + ctx.getBean("transactionManager"));
```

And here is the output:

```
>>> Datasource instance: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@1220ef43
>>> TransactionManager instance: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager@60cb1ed6
```

Comment: Its not working with my application. I am still getting same error. I will try your code and let you know.

Comment: Well, exclude more auto-configuration then ;). The likely candidates are: `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class`, `JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class`, and `JpaBaseConfiguration.class`.

Comment: Seems like I am running in loop of problems. Spring Boot is not at all reading configurations written in xml. None of my beans are getting initialized. I m getting below     exception.     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.boot.spring.service.PersonService com.boot.spring.controller.PersonController.personService;

Comment: I resolved this and posted my answer. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Doesn't my question and answer deserve some up votes?

Comment: @GD_Java I did. But not sure who downvoting you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a week ago, since I'm just starting to learn spring framework.  I tried, to manually configure the datasource of my spring boot application with bean declarations in configuration files(both java and xml configs).  Then I realized that spring boot was designed to make configuration easy for us. So I read about its [documentation on Database initialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html).  I think you can eliminate all those xml configuration of yours with the following lines in your ***application.properties*** file:

```
spring.datasource.type=org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQL5Dialect
```

And then annotate your entity classes with @Entity.  You can find more examples on JPA entity configuration [here](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/one-to-many-jpa-hibernate-config-jpa-entity-config.html).  If you want spring boot to automatically create and drop the database tables for you, add the following to your ***application.properties*** file:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

the default value is "*create*". You can also use "*update*" if you don't want the tables to be created automatically or if the tables are already existing. You can find more info on common application properties in the ***application.properties*** file [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

Comment: I do not want to use properties files. I have lot of configurations done in xml so I want to use xml only. There must be some fix for this issue, I am trying to figure out them.

Comment: You are excluding auto-configuration with @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class) but it seems you are not providing a DataSource configuration in your servlet-context.xml? Spring needs to have a way to configure a Datasource. With properties it does it automatically for you. Otherwise you need to declare a Datasource bean in your XML

Comment: I have done all configurations in servlet-context.xml file which I posted above. Is there anything wrong in that? If I do not use spring boot everything works fine.

Comment: may i ask why u dont like to configure in application property file ?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with configuration file schema configuration, can you please use following Schema condifiguration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">
```

beans:beans is conflicting into mvc schema. Beacuse beans:beans is referring to default xmlns which in your case is mvc schema

Comment: Sure I am in office right now. I will check this once I reach home and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

While Running application we are giving runtime argument like below.

-Dspring.config.location=/User/Properties/conf

But should add one forward slash at last like below. It will solve your problem.

-Dspring.config.location=/User/Properties/conf/

Comment: Make sure the DbConnection details properly in application.properties