# Not able to ref dataSource from other bean configuartion in Spring

Tags: spring

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
        <property name="poolName" value="${models.DS_POOL_NAME}" />

        </property>
    </bean>
<bean id="DBPlaceholder" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
        <property name="properties">
            <bean class="org.apache.commons.configuration2.ConfigurationConverter" factory-method="getProperties">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean id="DatabaseConfigurator" class="org.apache.commons.configuration2.DatabaseConfiguration">
                        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                        <property name="table" value="sample" />
                        <property name="keyColumn" value="PROPERTY" />
                        <property name="valueColumn" value="VALUE" />
                        <property name="configurationNameColumn" value="GROUP_NAME" />
                        <property name="configurationName" value="new" />
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

when we ref dataSource in DBPlaceholder bean then ${models.DS_POOL_NAME} will showing error because this value is coming from properties

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot not able to create datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36684444/spring-boot-not-able-to-create-datasource)

Comment: @Feras AI Sous Thank you for your comment. I am not using Spring Boot.Using only Spring core V4